# How to show a hidden <i> tag when clicked on an item

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

**HTML**

```
<li ng-class="{class : classVar==='Marketing' }" ng-click="changeClass('Marketing')">                           
    <i class="fa fa-pencil" style="visibility:hidden;"></i>
    Marketing
    <i class="fa fa-times" title="Close"  style="visibility:hidden;"></i>
</li>
<li ng-class="{class : classVar==='Sells' }" ng-click="changeClass('Sells')">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil" style="visibility:hidden;"></i>
    Sells Team Nestle
    <i class="fa fa-times" title="Close"  style="visibility:hidden;"></i>
</li>
```

**Angularjs**

```
$scope.changeClass = function(value){
       $scope.classVar= value; 
};
```

I want to show the hidden `<i>` tag when click on that `li` item. How to do this in angularjs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) for your purpouse

```
<li ng-class="{class : classVar==='Marketing' }" ng-click="changeClass('Marketing')">                           
    <i class="fa fa-pencil" ng-show="classVar === 'Marketing'"></i>
    Marketing
    <i class="fa fa-times" title="Close"  ng-show="classVar === 'Marketing'"></i>
</li>
<li ng-class="{class : classVar==='Sells' }" ng-click="changeClass('Sells')">
    <i class="fa fa-pencil" ng-show="classVar === 'Sells'"></i>
    Sells Team Nestle
    <i class="fa fa-times" title="Close"  ng-show="classVar === 'Marketing'"></i>
</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Set a variable in the controller

```
$scope.toShow = false;
```

When you clicked on an element, then change `toShow` value to `true` inside the `changeClass` function.

In HTML, try this

```
<i class="fa fa-times" title="Close" ng-show="toShow"></i>
```

Comment: this would messed up while using the same variable for all selection

Comment: This is just an example of how it can achieve. OP can modify for other variable and elements based on his code and requirements

Answer (score 0):

Add an `ng-if` condition to the `<i>`:

```
<i class="fa fa-pencil" ng-if="show" style="visibility:hidden;"></i>
```

In the `ng-click` do this:

```
ng-click="show = !show"
```

It will toggle the value of `show` and you don't even need a function in the controller.